# Query regarding Autocomplete TextView

Tags: autocompletetextview

I'm using an AutocompleteTextView which uses an arraylist of strings. My requirement is, I need the count of strings matching with arraylist to that of characters entered in the AutocompleteTextView widget.
Please suggest how to implement this functionality.

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have an ArrayList in hand in which you can search the words that starts with the letters typed. Use following method.

```
autocompletetextview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // set count to zero here

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // Do your search here

            }
        });
```

As you type inside the view, you get the text in the parameter 's'. Then use `element.startsWith(s)` for each element of the ArrayList. If true, increment the count.